# How to find duplicate records in oracle CASE WHEN Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, case-when

I have two tables like below. TABLEA and table TABLEB. We do outer join on TRANS_ID and compare both tables.

I want to get the result as shown in result. We check for duplicates in only TABLEA (i.e., based on TABLEA.TRANS_ID).

```
TABLEA
+------+----------+-------+--+-------------+
| UUID | TRANS_ID | NAME  |  | PHONENUMBER |
+------+----------+-------+--+-------------+
|  123 |     7928 | SCOTT |  | 87482837849 |
|  123 |     7928 | SCOTT |  | 87482837849 |
|  489 |     7493 | TOM   |  | 79274778397 |
|  827 |     7920 | DAVID |  | 23794928749 |
|  324 |     8472 | PAT   |  | 87927478839 |
+------+----------+-------+--+-------------+

TABLEB
+----------+----------+--------+-------------+
| BATCH_ID | TRANS_ID | SENDER | PHONENUMBER |
+----------+----------+--------+-------------+
|   823784 |     7438 | LSK    | 84748394092 |
|   793847 |     7493 | KLI    | 79274778397 |
|   748738 |     7920 | ISL    | 74892890487 |
+----------+----------+--------+-------------+

RESULT
+----------+-------------+-------------------------+
| TRANS_ID | PHONENUMBER |           STATUS        |
+----------+-------------+-------------------------+
|     7928 | 87482837849 |    DUPLICATE RECORD     |
|     7928 | 87482837849 |    NOT IN TABLEB        |
|     7438 | 84748394092 |    NOT IN TABLEA        |
|     7920 | 23794928749 |    PHONENUMBER MISMATCH |
|     8472 | 87927478839 |    NOT IN TABLEB        |
+----------+-------------+-------------------------+
```

I tried using below case when statement. I got all scenarios covered except for extracting duplicates. When there are duplicate records in TABLE A and they don't exist in TABLEB, the first record should be 'NOT IN TABLEB' and subsequent records should be 'DUPLICATE RECORD'

```
 CASE
          WHEN TABLEA.TRANS_ID is null THEN 'NOT IN TABLEA'
          WHEN TABLEB.TRANS_ID is null THEN 'NOT IN TABLEB' 
          WHEN decode(TABLEA.PHONENUMBER,ALRAJHI_TABLEB.PHONENUMBER,1,0)=0 THEN 'PHONENUMBER MISMATCH'             
          END
```

Comment: Why for `trans_id = 7928` one row display `DUPLICATE RECORD` and one row `NOT IN TABLEB` ? If you say `TABLEA` is master table the condition `TABLEA.TRANS_ID is null ` doesn't make sense to me ?

Comment: Sorry, this is not a parent child relation ship between these two. There are two tables with some data, possible scenarios are record can exist in table A, but not in table B and vice versa. Just for comparing duplicates we are only checking trans_id in table A not in table B.

Comment: I'd suggest you provide your full SQL query (rather than just the CASE portion) and the current result you are getting, to help understand your problem better.

Comment: Did you use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: It seems like you just need `ELSE 'DUPLICATE RECORD` as the last case.

Comment: Why do you use `DECODE()` instead of just `WHEN TABLEA.PHONENUMBER <> TABLEB.PHONENUMBER`?

Comment: Why is 7928 a duplicate record? It's not in TABLEB. Are you also looking for duplicates within the same table? That seems like a separate problem than comparing between the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
WITH x
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
                  OVER (
                    PARTITION BY CASE WHEN a.trans_id IS NULL THEN b.trans_id ELSE a.trans_id END
                    ORDER BY CASE WHEN a.trans_id IS NULL THEN b.trans_id ELSE a.trans_id END) AS rn,
                CASE WHEN a.trans_id IS NULL THEN b.trans_id ELSE a.trans_id END AS trans_id,
                CASE WHEN a.trans_id IS NULL THEN b.phonenumber ELSE a.phonenumber END AS phonenumber,
                CASE
                     WHEN a.trans_id IS NULL THEN 'NOT IN TABLEA'
                     WHEN b.trans_id IS NULL THEN 'NOT IN TABLEB'
                     WHEN DECODE(a.phonenumber, b.phonenumber, 1, 0) = 0 THEN 'PHONENUMBER MISMATCH'
                END AS status
         FROM   tablea a
                FULL OUTER JOIN tableb b
                             ON a.trans_id = b.trans_id),
y AS (
SELECT trans_id,
       phonenumber,
       CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN 'DUPLICATE RECORD' ELSE status END AS status
FROM   x)
SELECT * FROM y
WHERE  status IS NOT NULL -- Exclude TableA records that are (presumably) OK
```

[image: Result]

EDIT: Adjusted query to use second CTE (y) as NOT NULL filter on status was removing rows needed for the ROW_NUMBER() check.

Comment: This is working great, but the problem is when one/both records in TABLEA TRANS_ID '7928' is/are in TABLEB, I am not getting  'DUPLICATE RECORD' in the RESULT.

Comment: You can check the results with the sample data you provided at the fiddle I created at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e7f3cdc3f6106c2d5250ff4ba6e3bb21.  With Trans_ID 7928, the first entry shows 'Not in TableB' while the second entry (picked up by the CASE WHEN rn > 1 condition) is marked as 'Duplicate Record). Perhaps you could try some additional data in the fiddle to see if you can demonstrate/reproduce the issue you are encountering?

Comment: Can you check my fiddle? I have this record 7928 in both tableA and tableB, but it is a duplicate in tableA. It does not show as a duplicate in the result(Actually this record does not appear at all). [dbfiddle.uk/...](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=50fae77bb6de5b976b3ec70733173491)

Comment: @Raj, thanks for the example.  I've amended the query to handle that scenario.

Comment: I am sorry to keep coming back on this issue. This fix is working, but when I have this scenario like in the example here [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c718bef033b95dbe48ff6c3a427a7f59). I am getting 8 records with 'DUPLICATE RECORD' flag. Actually, I should be getting just three records with trans_id 7928 right?

Comment: You mentioned duplicates in TableA but not TableB, so what I believe is happening is each of the 7928 entries in TableA is matched with each of the 7928 entries in TableB, giving 9 combinations, but the first is not considered duplicate, hence 8.  Referring to your original question, you specifically said "We check for duplicates in only TABLEA"! Hence my assumption! Should be possible to tweak the query to handle the new scenario, when I get some time.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help! I found when there are duplicates in tableb, but single record in tablea I am getting DUPLICATE RECORD in the response. I think this is because of the join between two tables.

Comment: Yes, that's right, for the same reason. From the way you phrased your original question, iI took it to mean that there wouldn't be duplicates in TableB, only TableA.  It means there needs to be additional logic in the query to handle that situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do this using `union all` to bring in the duplicates from the first table:

```
select trans_id, coalesce(ta.phonenumber, tb.phonenumber) as phonenumber,
       (case when ta.phonenumber is null then 'NOT IN TABLEA'
             when tb.phonenumber is null then 'NOT IN TABLEB'
             else 'PHONENUMBER MISMATCH'
        end) as status
from (select distinct trans_id, phonenumber
      from tablea ta
     ) ta full join
     tableb tb
     using (trans_id)
where ta.phonenumber is null or tb.phonenumber is null or
      ta.phonenumber <> tb.phonenumber
union all
select trans_id, phonenumber, 'DUPLICATE RECORD'
from tablea
group by trans_id, phonenumber
having count(*) >= 2;
```